# urldate in BibTeX gets ignored

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I cite online ressources like this in my `.bib` file:

```
@misc{JavaCross,
  author = {Sun},
  title = {Java Sun: Definition Cross Plattform},
  note = {\url{http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed1/dg/higq.htm}},
  lastvisited = {2012-03-20},
}
```

the `lastvisited` doesnt work. It just gets ignored. I also tryed `lastchecked` and `urldate`, which I find on google.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell us, what kind of style you're using. What about creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ideally, you'd be using a bibliography style file -- the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` command -- that is set to recognize and process a field named "lastvisited". Which style file are you currently using?

If you can't obtain a suitable style file (extension `.bst`) that processes the contents of a field named "lastvisited", you could pursue either of the following strategies:

- First, you might combine the contents of the `note` and `lastvisited` fields into a single `note` field, i.e., combine

  ```
  note = {\url{http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed1/dg/higq.htm}},
  lastvisited = {2012-03-20},
  ```

  into

  ```
  note = {\url{http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed1/dg/higq.htm}, visited 2012-03-20},
  ```
- Second, if you're using a reasonably modern bib style file (i.e., which recognizes a field named `url`), you could (i) change the label "note" to "url" and (ii) change the label "lastvisited" to "note" and add "visited on" to the contents of the new `note` field.

  ```
  url = {\url{http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed1/dg/higq.htm}},
  note = {visited on 2012-03-20},
  ```

  Addendum: Some examples of reasonably modern bib style files (i.e., which recognize a field named `url`) are those that come with the `natbib` package: `plainnat.bst`, `unsrtnat.bst`, and `abbrvnat.bst`. They behave very much like the `plain`, `unsrt`, and `abbrv` style files while recognizing *five additional fields* -- `doi`, `eid`, `isbn`, `issn`, and `url` -- beyond the 22+ fields recognized by the original bib style files `plain`, `unsrt`, and `abbrv`.

Comment: I`m using "galpha2a". You´re post was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I can't find a file `galpha2a` anywhere. Is it a custom bibliography style?

Comment: to be honest, I dont know. I´m using the template of my professor. Sorry.

Comment: For random people finding this whose url field is ignored: howpublished did it for me (style: amsplain)!  Also top solution using the note field for it

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this thing too, [so I changed the IEEEtran.bst file](https://github.com/ionaic/bibtex-ieeetran-urldate) to include a urldate.

Currently it produces something like:

```
tex.stackexchange.com (Accessed March 4, 2016)
```

given:

```
@misc{example,
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {March 4, 2016}
}
```

Just search for "Accessed" in the file if you want to change that to some other phrase like "Last visited."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is a "CTLname variable"?

Comment: Oh sorry, just got out of a few ours of editing their code.  CTLname_X_Y are variables used for configuring the IEEEtran.bst bib style.  Specifically there's CTLname_url_prefix for changing what it outputs before a url, and I added another variable to allow configuration in a similar way (CTLname_urldate_prefix), but it's really not relevant so I removed it from the above post.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's probably too late now, but is it feasible for you to post the original file and your changes as seperate commits? I'm trying to figure out how to add this functionality to a different style (one of the Elsevier ones).

Comment: Thank you and +1. 2 hours of browsing and several attempts and only only solution really works. 
For those who thinking about trying biblatex: it looks ugly and can screw things up if you have 2 input languages