# Adding urldate to url function?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [urldate in BibTeX gets ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48983/urldate-in-bibtex-gets-ignored)

My university has their own .bst file for outputting references. But the urldate of internet articles is not included. There is a function format.url:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "URL \url{" url * "}" * }
    if$
}
```

Not familiar with bibtex syntax. How can I modify it to also print e.g. "(visited on 2012-04-12)"

Thanks!

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @Werner: I think this question is too localized. The op wrote that the bst file was created by the university. I think we can't support every private file.