# Having problem for citing online website in ieeestyle

Tags: citing

I'm having problem when I tried to cite an online website in my article. It does not  show url info at all. Here is my example code showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}


\begin{document}

I'm citing  \cite{SolarData} for ...

\bibliography{xx}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

where xx is my bib file as follows:

```
@ONLINE{SolarData,
    title = {Key Figures},
    url = {https://www.transnetbw.com/en/transparency/market-data/key-figures},
    date = {2018},
    urldate = {2018-09-01}
}
```

The output is for reference as follows:

> References [1] Key figures.

Can anybody help me, please?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you have the wrong bibliographic style to show the URL field. Change `plain` by `IEEEtran` for instance. This should show:

> [1] Key figures. [Online]. Available: https://...

Or by `vancouver`

> [1] Key Figures.  Available from: https://...

Or by `ChemEurJ`

> [1] *Key Figures*.  https://...

Or by `tufte`

> [1] "Key Figures", URL   https://...

Or by `plainurl`

> [1] Key figures. URL: https://...

etc.

If you want also show the `urldate` your will had to search another styles or make your own style. See [urldate in BibTeX gets ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48983/urldate-in-bibtex-gets-ignored).

Comment: It worked when I change the bibliographic style and delete all related existing files other than main tex and bib file. Thanks for the answer.